# GraalVM "Invalid GAV coordinates" error? (Spring boot 3)

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, graalvm

Recently I downloaded  Spring Boot 3 to test the embedded GraalVM. I run the `./gradlew native compile command the result is:

```bash
$ ./gradlew nativeCompile

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':nativeCompile'.
> Invalid GAV coordinates: groovy:it_groovy_comparre: (expected format: groupId:artifactId: version)

....

BUILD FAILED in 752ms
```

What is my problem with dependencies? When I run that command in debug mode there is nothing new except this error.

NOTE:

- my `$JAVA_HOME` variable value is: `/home/<my username>/.jdks/graalvm-ce-java17-22.3.0/`, which point to a Graalvm java
- my build automation tool is Gradle.
- When I tested the command in groovy the result was the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
Firstly I added a version to my `build.gradle` file like this :

```
plugins {
    // ...
}

group = 'groovy'
version = '1' // <-------------- HERE
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    //...
}
```

Just before executing the command `./gradlew nativeCompile`, I ran the following two commands :

```bash
$ ./gradlew processAot
...

$ ./gradlew processTestAot 
...
```

After that, everything works fine.